# "to be one to be successful" does this mean to be alone to be successful? or to be the one to succeed

Tags: meaning

"to be one to be successful".
Does this mean you need to be alone to get success? or to be the one to succeed

Comment: Not enough context at all.

Comment: It's a separate sentence I saw on the internet. Originally, I thought it was like an idiom that I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to decipher without context.

If it's part of the sentence "Two partners had to be one to be successful" then that's saying they have to "be one" in a metaphorical sense. It's symbolic, meaning they have to be very emotionally close with one another (so close they ), like marriage.

It could also be a part of the sentence "He was two people, and he had to be one to be successful" meaning his mind was pulled in multiple directions and he needed to focus one one thing to succeed.

It could be a part of a sentence like "she was surrounded by bad people, and she had to be one in order to be successful" meaning she had to do bad things in order to succeed.

Obviously these are very different answers and it all depends on what came before. Hopefully though you can apply this to that to figure out which answer it seems closest to.

Comment: Thank you very much.